# Move element left X increments on button click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an element I want to move left 800 px on each click of the button.

Ive written the following code only it moves my element left once and not on each click, can anybody suggest the correct method?

```
$('.hero-nav li.prev a').click(function(){
    $('.hero-carousel').animate({'margin-left':'-640px'}, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Isn't the link followed when you click?

Answer (score 9):

You're missing 1 important character....

```
$('.hero-nav li.prev a').click(function(){
    $('.hero-carousel').animate({'margin-left':'-=800px'}, 1000);
});
```

The = sign makes it move relatively.  Without it was moving absolutely.